# UI update after $http.post

Tags: angularjs, http-post, controllers

I want to update my controllers' states once I have finished with an $http.post in angular. I currently broadcast to the controllers that the state of module data has changed and that causes the controllers to refresh themselves. However, I am having issues implementing.

postModule:

```
angular.module('commandPoster',[]).
    service('commandPosterService', function($http) {
         this.postCommand(command, devMode, callback) {
            var path = "/client_api/command";

            if(devMode) {
                path = "/app_dev.php" + path;
            }

            $http.post(path, "commands=" + JSON.stringify(command), { headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} }).
                success(function() {
                   if(callback) {
                        console.log("callback");
                        callback();
                    }
                });

        }
    });
```

appModule:

```
angular.module('fittingApp', ['$strap.directives', 'commandPoster'])
    .service('fittingDataService', ['$rootScope', 'commandPosterService',
        function ($rootScope, poster) {

        function broadcastStateChange (msg) {
            msg = msg | "no msg";
            console.log("updating: " + msg);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('stateChange');
        }

        this.postCommand = function (command, devMode) {
            poster.postCommand(command, devMode, broadcastStateChange);
        };
    });
```

***EDIT:***

It seems like it doesn't go into the success handler. But I feel like it should. I am returning a response with $httpBackend in my tests.

Comment: Try to put a error function and see if you catch something...

Comment: I think I figured out the reason. I was looping over the posts so only the last post actually went into success.

Comment: Nice! I've some problems days ago with sequentials calls to $http methods, some of calls are missed... anyway, I've changed my code to make just one request. I don't know if its your case, but it's good to know =)